# Как динамические добавлять элементы Visual studio c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, visual-studio, desktop

Как достать записи из бд и динамически добавлять их в такой форме?
Какой компонент использовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это слишком общий вопрос? 1. Работа с базой, там сотня подходов к ней, от куда нам знать что у вас сейчас? 2. Компонент - очень сильно зависит от того, что вы используете (Web/WinForms/WPF, может Unity?) опять же, от куда нам знать? Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него как можно больше подробностей. И не забудьте приложить ваши попытки решения задачи.

Comment: Вообщем то вопрос в том как динамически создать компоненты ( кол-во = кол-во записей в бд ) Winfroms добавил.

Comment: Погуглить c# winform работа с БД.

Answer (score 2):

Вот отличное решение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Render();
        }

        void Render()
        {
            var controls = new List<Control>();
            var count = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var p = new Panel
                {
                    AutoScroll = true,
                    Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                    Margin = new Padding(10),
                    Controls =
                    {
                        new Label()
                        {
                            Text = (i + 1).ToString(),
                            Dock = DockStyle.Left,
                            Width = 50,
                            Height = 80,
                            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                            Margin = new Padding(5),
                            BackColor = Color.Transparent
                        },

                        new Panel()
                        {
                            Margin = new Padding(10),
                            Width = 500,
                            Dock = DockStyle.Right,
                            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                            Controls =
                            {
                                new Panel()
                                {
                                    Height = 60,
                                    Width = 200,
                                    Controls =
                                    {
                                        new Label() { Text = "text1:.....", Dock = DockStyle.Top},
                                        new Label() { Text = "text1:.....", Dock = DockStyle.Top},
                                        new Label() { Text = "text1:.....", Dock = DockStyle.Top}
                                    },
                                    Dock = DockStyle.Left

                                },
                                new Panel()
                                {
                                    Height = 60,
                                    Width = 200,
                                    Controls =
                                    {
                                        new Label() { Text = "text1:.....", Dock = DockStyle.Top},
                                        new Label() { Text = "text1:.....", Dock = DockStyle.Top},
                                        new Label() { Text = "text1:.....", Dock = DockStyle.Top}
                                    },
                                    Dock = DockStyle.Left,

                                },
                            }
                        },

                        new Panel()
                        {
                            Dock = DockStyle.Right,
                            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,

                            Controls =
                            {
                                new Label() { Text = "TEXT....", TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Height = 80}
                            }
                        }

                    }
                };
                controls.Add(p);
            }


            for (int i = controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Controls.Add(controls[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```